# In the Build Your First App tutorial, what is "actionbar_background" and how do I define it?

Tags: android

I'm working through the Android Build Your First App tutorials, and I've got to [Styling The Action Bar.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

I created this themes.xml file as per the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to define `actionbar_background`.
Of course, I get the following error:

> Error:(12, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'android:background' with value '@drawable/actionbar_background').

I guessed that it is a colour, but how do I define it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just as a quick "first build" thing you can change to a color code, like this:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#aaaaaa</item>
</style>
```

but in you can make it to be any `color` or `drawable`.

Colors are usually defined in a separate file like this:

`colors.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resources>
    <color name="disabled_text">#9FFF</color>
    <color name="actionbar">#000</color>
    <color name="background">#111</color>
 ... etc

</resources>
```

and `drawables` are defined as `.png` files placed in your `drawables-...` folders, or define as `XML` files in the `drawables` folder.

then referenced on the styles like this:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/disabled_text</item>
</style>
```

or for a actionbar_background.png in the `drawables-...` folders

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I understand the @color/disabled_text line perfectly, but am struggling a bit with referencing a .png file to define a colour.  Would that just a plain rectangle of colour?

Comment: DO NOT user a `.png` file to define a color. If you want to use just a color, use a color. If you want to have a full graphical thing, then you use a `.png`

Comment: Do you mean, like a pattern?  I'm just a bit confused because the tutorial seems to intend to reference a .png file, because it says @drawable...it would be simpler and more obvious to reference a color, surely?

Comment: for example, you want the actionbar background to have some fadinf border, or a pattern with stripes or red dots... yeah, then `.png` but for just a simple color, use the color

Answer (score 0):

Create the file drawable/actionbar_background.xml with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="#ffcf6413"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff4842c"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```